# I hit Ctrl+d while in a screen session, how do I now send commands?

Tags: gnu-screen

I was trying to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>, and failed miserably and input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> instead, now the screen won't respond to my commands. They appear, and the app running in the screen (a minecraft server) is still ticking along nicely, but I can't issue the server commands.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> works and reconnecting with `screen -r -d -S minecraft` works fine, but no commands register.

Any way to regain control?

Comment: Maybe you've pressed CTRL+S instead? Try pressing CTRL+Q and see what happens.

Comment: No effect from CTRL+q or CTRL+Q.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> is usually configured to generate the EOF signal which for most shells by default signifies the end of input to the shell and the shell terminates. However, you have started another process (minecraft) in the shell so it is waiting for that process to terminate.

There is no way to undo this.

To prevent this in the future, assuming you are using bash, set the environment variable `IGNOREEOF` to a number greater than 1 and you'll need to accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> that many times.

Comment: I thought it might be something along these lines, but had no idea of a solution - I can do that, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this particular post when I needed a solution for the exact same problem. I *think* I stumbled upon the answer by accident after reading through this and trying things in the "dead" screen window.

**The situation:** I use "set -o vi" in bash for my command line editor. I used "ESC k" to scroll back.  I meant to press CTRL-C to cancel back to an empty prompt, but pressed CTRL-D by mistake.  When I did that, that window in screen locked up...screen itself was still fine, and all other screen windows were fine.

**The solution(?):** I found that sending XOFF (ctrl-s) followed by XON (ctrl-q) it "unfroze" the window.  Sending XON alone--without first sending XOFF--*didn't* work.

However, I've been totally unable to reproduce the CTRL-D lockup. I have no idea what set of conditions existed to cause it!  Since I can't reproduce the problem, I can't test my solution, so I don't know if I actually found the solution or if it just happened to "fix itself" somehow after some length of time. *shrug*

If anyone gets the opportunity to test this, please reply!  :o)